# Get total count entry by today in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get total count by a user for today. Current Symfony version 2.8

```php
 $repo = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Transaction");

 $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')->where("DATE_DIFF(u.created, CURRENT_DATE()) = 0")
                            ->andWhere("u.user_id = ".$winner->getId());

 $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

created and user_id is database entity. But code is not working after adding this.

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: I am new to this language, just it's not working when adding it.

Comment: Yes, but what did you say by `not working`? It's return nothing, it's throwing an error, etc?

Comment: How to check error on server I don't know. Just using as API in Android and it's not working. I am Android developer.

Comment: It seems that you wait a count. The SQL query does not contain any `count` it is normal?

Comment: I want total count from transaction table where date=today date and user= winner.

Comment: running 2.8 symfony version.

Answer (score 0):

Add a select with a count in it.

This is from a working example, really used:

```
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb
            ->select('COUNT(e)')
            ->from('App:SpareTime', 'e')
            ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->between(':from', 'e.startDateTime', 'e.endDateTime'),
                $qb->expr()->between(':to', 'e.startDateTime', 'e.endDateTime'),
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->lte(':from', 'e.startDateTime'),
                    $qb->expr()->gte(':to', 'e.endDateTime')
                )
            ))
            ->setParameter('from', $from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('to', $to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

$from and $to are DateTime objects.

Comment: then I need to use this  $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();  ?

Comment: Do according to me please. I don't know what to change where. I know syntax of this language only.

Comment: running 2.8 symfony version.

Comment: *facepalm* Mea culpa! My fault!